# Can I use Visual Studio Snippets to generate SQL code

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I want to use Visual Studio snippets to generate SQL code, for example we have standard naming conventions for foreign keys etc and it would be great if I could just expand a snippet in my SQL script file.

However as far as I can tell the only languages that are supported by the Snippet manager are C#, VB J# and XML

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms171421(VS.80).aspx

Does anyone know of a way to have a snippet expand to SQL?

Derek

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you consider using [T4](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/make-visual-studio-generate-your-repository/), which is built into Visual Studio.

Oleg has great examples, including one for [stored procedures](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/01/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-crud-stored-procedures/)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 added support for SQL snippets.

You can read more about them at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362022.aspx)